# Getting rid of old transactions

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

A few times I have attempted to send Monero, but the fee was too small, so I now have a bunch showing "Pending" I have already resent them with higher fees successfully. But now Im afraid that they may get actioned as well. Can I remove them? My unlocked balance is looking quite low too. Should I just hit "rescan spent" ?

Using the GUI wallet

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can type the following command in the monerod, it is the black square box with many text named "monerod".

```
flush_txpool
```

This should clear all your pending transactions. However, if there is a backlogged or your transaction is already in the mempool it may not work, so just try it.